# Is it possible to change encoding to UTF-8 without opening the file?

Tags: encoding, console

I have huge file (700mb) which has to be opened, changed encoding and then saved. Isn't there any other way how to do that? Maybe using console or any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iconv utility is handy on Linux.

It has also been ported to Windows. Download the binary and try it on a command line:

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Well, I hope GNU C library will stay for very long time. It's a pitty that Microsoft does not ship it ;-)